# How can I connect to a mysql database with LINE bot?

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I've recently got LINE Bot working on my hosting.
https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-php

I can get it to talk back pretty easy using a setup I found here - https://github.com/afifmakarim/bot-line-simple

This is the confusing part, I get lost in the code due to insufficient knowledge of namespaces. Apparently, to get my LINE Bot to retrieve data from mysql database and send it back as a message, I need to use a namespace class.

Anyway I'm lost, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Edit:
Here is index.php

```
            <?php

            require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
            include 'include/dbconfig.php';
            include 'include/function.php';

            use\ LINE\ LINEBot\ SignatureValidator as SignatureValidator;

             load config
            $dotenv = new Dotenv\ Dotenv( __DIR__ );
            $dotenv->load();

             initiate app
            $configs = [
                settings' => [ 'displayErrorDetails' => true ],
            ];
            $app = new Slim\ App( $configs );

             ROUTES 
            $app->get( '/', function ( $request, $response ) {
                return "Working!";
            } );

            $app->post( '/', function ( $request, $response ) {
                 get request body and line signature header
                $body = file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
                $signature = $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_X_LINE_SIGNATURE' ];

                 log body and signature
                file_put_contents( 'php://stderr', 'Body: ' . $body );

                 is LINE_SIGNATURE exists in request header?
                if ( empty( $signature ) ) {
                    return $response->withStatus( 400, 'Signature not set' );
                }

                 is this request comes from LINE?
                if ( $_ENV[ 'PASS_SIGNATURE' ] == false && !SignatureValidator::validateSignature( $body, $_ENV[ 'CHANNEL_SECRET' ], $signature ) ) {
                    return $response->withStatus( 400, 'Invalid signature' );
                }

                 init bot
                $httpClient = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ HTTPClient\ CurlHTTPClient( $_ENV[ 'CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN' ] );
                $bot = new\ LINE\ LINEBot( $httpClient, [ 'channelSecret' => $_ENV[ 'CHANNEL_SECRET' ] ] );
                $data = json_decode( $body, true );
                foreach ( $data[ 'events' ] as $event ) {
                    $userMessage = $event[ 'message' ][ 'text' ];
                    $msgchunk = explode( " ", $userMessage );
                    Hello Example
                    if ( strtolower( $msgchunk[ 0 ] ) == 'hello' ) {
                        if ( strtolower( $msgchunk[ 1 ] ) == 'you' ) {
                            $message = "Hi you";
                            $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                            $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                            return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();

                        } else {
                            $message = "Hi";
                            $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                            $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                            return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                        }
                    }
                    Search for something
                    if ( strtolower( $msgchunk[ 0 ] ) == 'search' ) {
                        if ( strtolower( $msgchunk[ 1 ] ) == 'id' ) {
                            if ( !$msgchunk[ 2 ] ) {
                                $message = "Please include an id to search for.";
                                $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                                $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                                return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                            } else {
                                This is where i want it to retrieve data from mysql database using the getName($userid) function.
                                $message = getName($db_con,$userid);
                                $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                                $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                                return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $message = "What do you want to search for?
                            Try, Search id or Search Sub";
                            $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                            $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                            return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                        }
                    }
                    if ( strtolower( $userMessage ) == 'add member' ) {
                        $message = "Adding Member";
                        $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                        $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();

                    }
                    if ( strtolower( $userMessage ) == 'find member' ) {
                        $message = "Finding Member";
                        $textMessageBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TextMessageBuilder( $message );
                        $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $textMessageBuilder );
                        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();

                    }
                    if ( strtolower( $userMessage ) == 'ihelp' ) {
                        $carouselTemplateBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateBuilder\ CarouselTemplateBuilder( [
                            new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateBuilder\ CarouselColumnTemplateBuilder(
                                "Search",
                                "use this to search for member id.",
                                "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/characters/8/320273.jpg", [
                                    new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ TemplateActionBuilder\ UriTemplateActionBuilder( 'Search', "Search id 15361839" ),
                                ] ),
                            new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateBuilder\ CarouselColumnTemplateBuilder(
                                "Sub",
                                "use this to get a list of subs for an id",
                                "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/characters/8/320273.jpg", [
                                    new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ TemplateActionBuilder\ UriTemplateActionBuilder( 'Sub', "Sub id 15361839" ),
                                ] ),
                        ] );
                        $templateMessage = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateMessageBuilder( 'template name', $carouselTemplateBuilder );
                        $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $templateMessage );
                        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                    }
                    if ( strtolower( $userMessage ) == "help" ) {
                        $buttonTemplateBuilder = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateBuilder\ ButtonTemplateBuilder(
                            "title",
                            "text",
                            "https://i0.wp.com/angryanimebitches.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/tamakomarket-overallreview-tamakoanddera.jpg", [
                                new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ TemplateActionBuilder\ MessageTemplateActionBuilder( 'Action Button', 'action' ),
                            ] );
                        $templateMessage = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ TemplateMessageBuilder( 'template name', $buttonTemplateBuilder );
                        $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $templateMessage );
                        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                    }
                    if ( $userMessage == "Send image" ) { //your message
                        $imageMessage = new\ LINE\ LINEBot\ MessageBuilder\ ImageMessageBuilder( "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/characters/8/320273.jpg", "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/characters/8/320273.jpg" );
                        $result = $bot->replyMessage( $event[ 'replyToken' ], $imageMessage );
                        return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
                    }
                }


            } );

             $app->get('/push/{to}/{message}', function ($request, $response, $args)
             {
                $httpClient = new \LINE\LINEBot\HTTPClient\CurlHTTPClient($_ENV['CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN']);
                $bot = new \LINE\LINEBot($httpClient, ['channelSecret' => $_ENV['CHANNEL_SECRET']]);

                $textMessageBuilder = new \LINE\LINEBot\MessageBuilder\TextMessageBuilder($args['message']);
                $result = $bot->pushMessage($args['to'], $textMessageBuilder);

                return $result->getHTTPStatus() . ' ' . $result->getRawBody();
             });

             JUST RUN IT 
            $app->run();
```

Here is function.php

```
            <?php

            function getName( $db_con, $userid ) {
                $dstmt = $db_con->prepare( "SELECT * FROM players WHERE p_id=:userid" );
                $dstmt->bindParam( ":userid", $userid );
                $dstmt->execute();
                $drow = $dstmt->fetch();
                return $drow[ 'pname' ];

            }

            ?>
```

Here is dbconfig.php

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "*****";
$db_user = "*****";
$db_pass = "*****";

try{

    $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
    $dbh = $db_con;
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is what I've tried and it doesn't work. If anyone wants to point anything out please do. 
I am not trying to be an expert coder it's just a hobby I seem to have developed.

Comment: Have your read about namespaces [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)? Start there. Other than that, your question is very unclear. Where exactly are you stuck, doing what? You've just linked to a couple of repos and mentioned "retrieve data from mysql" which doesn't really say much.

Comment: Why do you need namespaces to read something from a database?

Comment: I've edited the post with some more information, my first time posting. I've usually found what I've been looking for with a quick Google.

Comment: i've solved it, do i put my own answer? Newb alert